# R Unused argument in KNN

Tags: r, algorithm, knn

I am trying to apply the KNN algorithm to a large dataset, but at the moment I keep getting an error. See the code below:

```
df <- list(`digits/trainingDigits/0_0.txt` = c(0, 1, 1, 0), `digits/trainingDigits/0_1.txt` = c(0, 1, 0, 0), `digits/trainingDigits/0_10.txt` = c(0, 0, 1, 0))

df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df))

df2 <- list(c(0, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 0))
df2 <- t(as.data.frame(df2))

df3 <- c(0, 1, 0)
df3 <- t(as.data.frame(df3))

library(FNN)

knn(train=df, test=df2, cl=df3, k=5, norm = FALSE)
```

The train set should be a dataset with four variables and three observations.

The test set should be a dataset with four variables and two observations.

The class should be a dataframe with one variable and three observations-

When applying the algorithm it says:

Error in knn(train = df, test = df2, cl = df3, k = 5, norm = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (norm = FALSE)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no `norm` parameter in this function.

Comment: Thank you, that's right.